# Pythonanywhere: Twitter API authenticates from bash, but fails on scheduled task

Tags: python, api, twitter, pythonanywhere

I'm using the `python-twitter` (not `tweepy`) module in my application.

I have a script set up (`maketweet.py`) that, when I run it from bash / console, works successfully (i.e. it makes a tweet).

The problem I'm having is that when I run the same script as a scheduled task, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dir1/dir2/proj/maketweet.py", line 21, in <module>
    api = create_api()
  File "/home/dir1/dir2/proj/config.py", line 31, in create_api
    if api.VerifyCredentials():
  File "/home/dir1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twitter/api.py", line 4699, in VerifyCredentials
    resp = self._RequestUrl(url, 'GET', data)
  File "/home/dir1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twitter/api.py", line 4959, in _RequestUrl
    raise TwitterError("The twitter.Api instance must be authenticated.")
twitter.error.TwitterError: The twitter.Api instance must be authenticated.
```

The other problem I'm having is that I can't conceive why it would make a difference that I'm using a scheduled task, rather than running the file directly from bash. Here are the contents of `config.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8

import twitter
import os
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv

logger = logging.getLogger()

# project folder is one level up from file location
project_folder = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))

# Authenticate to Twitter and create API object
TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY = os.getenv("TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY")
TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_SECRET = os.getenv("TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_SECRET")

TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv("TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN")
TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET = os.getenv("TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET")

def create_api():

    # Create API object
    api = twitter.Api(
        access_token_key = TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        access_token_secret = TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET,
        consumer_key = TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY,
        consumer_secret = TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_SECRET,
        sleep_on_rate_limit=True)

    # test API object
    if api.VerifyCredentials():
        pass
    else:
        logger.error("Error creating API", exc_info=True)
        raise Exception("Twitter user authentication error")

    logger.info("API created")
    return api
```

Obviously there's an error in creating the API. I imagine this has something to do with the environment variables and how they are accessed through scheduled tasks vs. bash. Just really not sure how to figure this one out...

Comment: Log your working directory in both cases (bash and task) to see what happens. You may also check values you are passing to the `twitter.Api`

Comment: @Filip I changed the way the scipt works in terms of working directory, so should be around that issue -- thank you for the tip :)

The twitter.Api authenticates on bash, so I imagine the values can't be incorrect?

Maybe I need to give pythonanywhere some waiting time / some retries to authenticate?

Comment: I just realized `pythonanywhere` on the free plan restricts you to outbound access only -- does that mean OAuth just isn't going to work (https://www.pythonanywhere.com/pricing/)?

Comment: OAuth should not be a problem.